# Is it possible to prevent the web/DB admin from peeking my online content?

Tags: security, web-applications, encryption

Let's say, there is a website for an online diary. Users upload their secrets to the web server and stored in the database. Normally, a user without the password can't see the diary items. However the web admin or DB admin could still can connect to the DB and see everything.

Is there a solution to prevent this? I mean a solution for the whole web application, not only for a single user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side javascript can encrypt the content, using a key known only to the client and never sent to the server, prior to saving.

However, the server can at any time start serving up malicious JS that would send the keys back down to the server. The only way to make this impossible is to make your application an installable client-side app (via an extension or whatever - but nothing that auto-updates). Additionally, all of this paranoia is pointless unless the user can verify what the app is doing, so it would need to be open-source.

At this point you're basically writing GnuPG, so you might as well just use that.